# How to update chrome driver in selenide using Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenide

I am newbie to the selenium and also to Java. There is existing codebase using selenide 5.16.2

The issue I am facing is,

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created:
 This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114 
Current browser version is 117.0.5938.92 with binary path C:\Program
 Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe.
```

In my windows system, I am currently having chrome 117 installed.
I am not sure how I can update the chrome driver version as whatever online references I checked, I could not find a way.

So it will be really helpful if I get some hints. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should't need to download or install anything manually. Selenide up to 6.16 used [WebDriverManager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) to automatically download and setup a suitable driver for you. As mentioned in its [blog](https://selenide.org/2023/08/02/selenide-6.17.0/#replace-webdrivermanager-by-selenium-manager), starting with version 6.17.0 selenide uses [*SeleniumManager*](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/) instead, which also manages drivers automatically for you.

Maybe just try to update *Selenide* to a more recent version.

Answer (score 0):

You have message, why you got this problem. ("This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114").

"5.16.2" version from 2020 year :)

Install in your maven or gradle project file (it depends) 6.19.1 for Selenide and I think your problem will be solved.

Or install lower than 114 Chrome version.